# How to select the past three months data from a date parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, parameters, count

I would like to display the name of the month along with a count for each of these months. But I only want the past 3 months from a date parameter that the user will select.

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(month, DateDue),
    COUNT(SiteAudit.SiteAuditID) AS SiteAuditID
FROM 
    SiteAudit
WHERE
    DateDue >= Dateadd(month, -3, @Date) 
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month, DateDue)
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong because now I am getting more than 3 months returned.

If anyone could please help I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query includes several product specific functions.

Comment: can you give an example of data with current results and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DateDue between DateAdd(month, -3, @Date) and @Date`
Your original query will select data which due date after the `@Date`

Complete query:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(month, DateDue),
    COUNT(SiteAudit.SiteAuditID) AS SiteAuditID
FROM 
    SiteAudit
WHERE
    DateDue BETWEEN Dateadd(month, -3, @Date) AND @Date
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month, DateDue)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for the quick help.